# Unable to call script with parameter and scriptfile

Tags: powershell

I'm unable to call powershell with start-process when i'm passing both scriptfile and parameters

```
start-process powershell d:\startTask.ps1 "param1" "param2" "param3"
```

My startTask.ps1 looks like below

```
param([string]$x="default",[string]$y="default",[string]$z="default")
echo "x: $x"
echo "y: $y"
echo "z: $z"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
Start-Process Powershell -ArgumentList "-noexit","-File d:\startTask.ps1 param1 param2 param3"
```

Comment: The key thing to note here is the use of `-ArgumentList`. The OP's arguments are all going to the command he's calling, `Start-Process`, and not Powershell like he thinks.

Answer (score 1):

```
& powershell d:\startTask.ps1 "param1" "param2" "param3"
```